# Is setting by reference local variable equivalent to helper function I have created

Tags: c#

I have the following code created after using ILSpy on a DLL:

```
ref Vector3 reference4 = ref vertices[vertexIndex + 3];
```

Using it in this context results in error:

```
error CS8176: Iterators cannot have by-reference locals
```

Is the code above equivalent to the following variable initialization with the helper function:

```
        private Vector3 getElement(Vector3[] array, int i)
        {
            return array[i];
        }
        


        Vector3[] vertices = textInfo.meshInfo[materialReferenceIndex].vertices;
        ......
        ......
        Vector3 reference3 = getElement(vertices, vertexIndex + 3);
```

Update: The entire original function looks like this:

```
        private IEnumerator WarpText()
        {
            VertexCurve.preWrapMode = WrapMode.Once;
            VertexCurve.postWrapMode = WrapMode.Once;
            m_TextComponent.havePropertiesChanged = true;
            CurveScale *= 10f;
            float old_CurveScale = CurveScale;
            AnimationCurve old_curve = CopyAnimationCurve(VertexCurve);
            while (true)
            {
                if (!m_TextComponent.havePropertiesChanged && old_CurveScale == CurveScale && old_curve.keys[1].value == VertexCurve.keys[1].value)
                {
                    yield return null;
                    continue;
                }
                old_CurveScale = CurveScale;
                old_curve = CopyAnimationCurve(VertexCurve);
                m_TextComponent.ForceMeshUpdate();
                TMP_TextInfo textInfo = m_TextComponent.textInfo;
                int characterCount = textInfo.characterCount;
                if (characterCount == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                float boundsMinX = m_TextComponent.bounds.min.x;
                float boundsMaxX = m_TextComponent.bounds.max.x;
                for (int i = 0; i < characterCount; i++)
                {
                    if (textInfo.characterInfo[i].isVisible)
                    {
                        int vertexIndex = textInfo.characterInfo[i].vertexIndex;
                        int materialReferenceIndex = textInfo.characterInfo[i].materialReferenceIndex;
                        Vector3[] vertices = textInfo.meshInfo[materialReferenceIndex].vertices;
                        Vector3 vector = new Vector2((vertices[vertexIndex].x + vertices[vertexIndex + 2].x) / 2f, textInfo.characterInfo[i].baseLine);
                        vertices[vertexIndex] += -vector;
                        vertices[vertexIndex + 1] += -vector;
                        vertices[vertexIndex + 2] += -vector;
                        vertices[vertexIndex + 3] += -vector;
                        float num = (vector.x - boundsMinX) / (boundsMaxX - boundsMinX);
                        float num2 = num + 0.0001f;
                        float y = VertexCurve.Evaluate(num) * CurveScale;
                        float y2 = VertexCurve.Evaluate(num2) * CurveScale;
                        Vector3 lhs = new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f);
                        Vector3 rhs = new Vector3(num2 * (boundsMaxX - boundsMinX) + boundsMinX, y2) - new Vector3(vector.x, y);
                        float num3 = Mathf.Acos(Vector3.Dot(lhs, rhs.normalized)) * 57.29578f;
                        float z = ((!(Vector3.Cross(lhs, rhs).z > 0f)) ? (360f - num3) : num3);
                        Matrix4x4 matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0f, y, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, z), Vector3.one);
                        ref Vector3 reference = ref vertices[vertexIndex];
                        reference = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex]);
                        ref Vector3 reference2 = ref vertices[vertexIndex + 1];
                        reference2 = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 1]);
                        ref Vector3 reference3 = ref vertices[vertexIndex + 2];
                        reference3 = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 2]);
                        ref Vector3 reference4 = ref vertices[vertexIndex + 3];
                        reference4 = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 3]);
                        vertices[vertexIndex] += vector;
                        vertices[vertexIndex + 1] += vector;
                        vertices[vertexIndex + 2] += vector;
                        vertices[vertexIndex + 3] += vector;
                    }
                }
                m_TextComponent.UpdateVertexData();
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.025f);
            }
        }
```

Comment: A `Vector3` is not the same thing as a `ref Vector3`, no. If `reference3` is modified, it will not modify `vertices[vertexIndex + 3]`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I've read about references now. Still looking for the way to change the original code properly...

Comment: Without more context it's impossible to tell, though if the only problem was that there's `ref` construct in an iterator it should be fairly easy to refactor those bits out to a helper method and reduce the iterator to the minimum possible (`yield return functionThatDoesAllTheActualWorkWithRefLocals()`).

Comment: Posted the original function. Looking at the same time of the way, how to make it work.

Comment: All uses of `ref` occur inside a single `if` and that block only uses `textInfo`, `boundsMinX` and `boundsMaxX`. Extract method with those as parameters, done.

Comment: Done. Thank you so much! 

P.S. It helped me to start learning of how this all comes together, i.e. for example will remember this particular rule and how to deal with it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as [@Jeroen Mostert mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258452/is-setting-by-reference-local-variable-equivalent-to-helper-function-i-have-crea/69260201#comment122414275_69258452), is to extract the code into a separate method, so it is not part of the for loop:

```
private void setVertices(TMP_TextInfo textInfo, float boundsMinX, float boundsMaxX)
{
    int vertexIndex = textInfo.characterInfo[i].vertexIndex;
    int materialReferenceIndex = textInfo.characterInfo[i].materialReferenceIndex;
    Vector3[] vertices = textInfo.meshInfo[materialReferenceIndex].vertices;
    Vector3 vector = new Vector2((vertices[vertexIndex].x + vertices[vertexIndex + 2].x) / 2f, textInfo.characterInfo[i].baseLine);
    vertices[vertexIndex] += -vector;
    vertices[vertexIndex + 1] += -vector;
    vertices[vertexIndex + 2] += -vector;
    vertices[vertexIndex + 3] += -vector;
    float num = (vector.x - boundsMinX) / (boundsMaxX - boundsMinX);
    float num2 = num + 0.0001f;
    float y = VertexCurve.Evaluate(num) * CurveScale;
    float y2 = VertexCurve.Evaluate(num2) * CurveScale;
    Vector3 lhs = new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f);
    Vector3 rhs = new Vector3(num2 * (boundsMaxX - boundsMinX) + boundsMinX, y2) - new Vector3(vector.x, y);
    float num3 = Mathf.Acos(Vector3.Dot(lhs, rhs.normalized)) * 57.29578f;
    float z = ((!(Vector3.Cross(lhs, rhs).z > 0f)) ? (360f - num3) : num3);
    Matrix4x4 matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0f, y, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, z), Vector3.one);
    ref Vector3 reference = ref vertices[vertexIndex];
    reference = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex]);
    ref Vector3 reference2 = ref vertices[vertexIndex + 1];
    reference2 = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 1]);
    ref Vector3 reference3 = ref vertices[vertexIndex + 2];
    reference3 = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 2]);
    ref Vector3 reference4 = ref vertices[vertexIndex + 3];
    reference4 = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 3]);
    vertices[vertexIndex] += vector;
    vertices[vertexIndex + 1] += vector;
    vertices[vertexIndex + 2] += vector;
    vertices[vertexIndex + 3] += vector;
}


TMP_TextInfo textInfo = m_TextComponent.textInfo;
int characterCount = textInfo.characterCount;
if (characterCount == 0)
{
    continue;
}
float boundsMinX = m_TextComponent.bounds.min.x;
float boundsMaxX = m_TextComponent.bounds.max.x;
for (int i = 0; i < characterCount; i++)
{
    if (textInfo.characterInfo[i].isVisible)
    {
        setVertices(textInfo, boundsMinX, boundsMaxX);
    }
}
```